# Trying to use :not to select ids and have the respective slideshows turn off

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

This is not being recognised.  I get a syntax error saying

```
illegal character on column 29.
```

When clicking any button (`#c1` - `#c4`) the slider stops. I believe that it isn't recognising the not.

```
$('div.nivoSlider:not('#c' + id)').data('nivoslider').stop();
```

Yet to start a specific slideshow this is working.

```
$('#c' + id).nivoSlider({ effect: 'fade' });
```

I initially have slider `#c1` starting on load.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are cutting off your string too early. (Look at the syntax highlighting colors here for the clue)

Try this:

```
$('div.nivoSlider:not(#c' + id + ')').data('nivoslider').stop();
```

Comment: I was able to gleam that from your code, and that's what my answer provides as well. If this answer fixes your code please mark it as "Accepted" for future visitors.

Comment: THank you DOOMManiac  So your way treats everything inside of the open bracket as a string and then place a closed bracket. I will try it. I will definitely mark as accepted as soon as I try it. :)

Comment: The code is accepted with no syntax error but it is not functioning as if it is reading the not. It stops the nivoslider #c1 . even if I take id out and place a number ('div.nivoSlider:not(#c' + 3 + ')').data('nivoslider').stop();

Comment: I wonder if it is because the jquery will return 3 items. and 2 of the items won't even have a nivoslider to turn off. I guess that I have more checking to do. I may have to post a new question on this.

Answer (score 0):

People here have been so generous with their time and knowledge. thank you. I thought that I would post what I ended up doing to get this to work. I didn't need any If statements at all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var runningSlider = 1;

     $('#slideButtons button').click(function(){        
         var newID = $(this).attr("id");
         alert (newID);
         alert ('test of variable ' + runningSlider);
         $('#c' + runningSlider).data('nivoslider').stop();     
         $('#c' + newID).data('nivoslider').start();
        runningSlider = newID;
    });
</script>
```